# Enable cookies with HTTPClient

Tags: java, cookies, web-crawler, httpclient

I am trying to implement a Java Code that fetch urls like this one:
http://trendistic.indextank.com/_trending-topics-archive/2011-12-25

The code I wrote is based in HTTPClient as follow:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Create a local instance of cookie store
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    // Create local HTTP context
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls);

    try {
        System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line+"\n");
        }
        System.out.println(total);

        return (total.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, the response I got is:

```
if (tz != tzless.readCookie('local_tz')) {
    // no cookies!
    document.write("<h1>Cookies are not enabled for this site</h1>");
    document.write("<p>In order for Trendistic to work in Internet Explorer you need to enable cookies.</p>");
    document.write("<ul><li>Please enable cookies for this site and refresh this page</li><li>Or try Trendistic in a different browser such as Safari, Firefox or Chrome.</li></ul>");
} else {
    self.location.reload();
}
```

How can I enable cookies for fetching the HTML with the dynamical results.

Comment: May try adding user-agent and other requied parameters:  httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
    HttpMethodParams.USER_AGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2"
);
May be try setting user-agent and other required parameters,

Comment: Typically a website sets a cookie in its response, redirects to another url, and expects to see the cookie there.  It it is missing then it sends the "cookies not enabled" message.  Can you confirm using your pageview logs that the redirect is happening?  Or maybe you should look into how the website is testing for cookies.

Comment: I tried adding:
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
 //also
        //httpclient.getParams().setParameter("Accept", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

but it didn't work. How can I check the redirect?

Comment: Solved adding the cookies manually as: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html#d4e777
Thank you all ;)

Comment: @supersoft thanks for the update; you should post it as an answer and accept ;)